# Remote Debug Java Web application in Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you connect an eclipse to a WebSphere Application server hosted on remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028984/how-do-you-connect-an-eclipse-to-a-websphere-application-server-hosted-on-remote)

I want to debug remote java web application in my local. I have the source code setup in eclipse.

I have started the server in debug mode.I have kept breakpoints in one of the filter and accessed the remote URL like  "http://192.167.123.543:9080/WebApp/test.do".

But the eclipse is not stopping at the break point. I am confused here with debug feature..

How does the breakpoints will come to local machine from remote URL? any help

Comment: Not exactly here I have question on "WebApplication" which is running on the server.Java application may be easy. I am not sure how it works for WAR file.

Comment: That is exactly what the referenced question is regarding. WAS runs web applications (WARs) and other Java EE applications, not plain Java applications. You should be able to follow the same steps described in my answer there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup a debug configuration in eclipse that points at the debug port on the server

Comment: so,anyone who is hitting the server, will be hitting my eclipse breakpoint..?

Comment: yes, that is remote debugging